# grails groovy version issue

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy, nosuchmethoderror

I have a grails application with 2.4.1 grails version and used 2.3 groovy compiler.

I am getting following error when I try to run

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.count(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Ljava/lang/Number;
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.web.ControllerActionTransformer.processMethods(ControllerActionTransformer.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.web.ControllerActionTransformer.performInjectionOnAnnotatedClass(ControllerActionTransformer.java:204)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.web.ControllerActionTransformer.performInjection(ControllerActionTransformer.java:196)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.injection.GrailsAwareInjectionOperation.call(GrailsAwareInjectionOperation.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1213)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:645)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:623)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:600)
    at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.internal.compiler.ast.GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.processToPhase(GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.java:185)
    at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.internal.compiler.ast.GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.analyseCode(GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.java:2213)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:834)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ProcessTaskManager.run(ProcessTaskManager.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Answer (score 0):

Grails 2.4.1 shipped with Groovy 2.3.3 and that is the only version of Groovy supported with that version of Grails.  Normally you don't do anything to associate a version of Groovy with a version of Grails.  Grails uses the version that is shipped with it.

Make sure that your GRAILS_HOME points to Grails 2.4.1 and that GRAILS_HOME/bin is on your PATH.  If you have a different version of Grails on your PATH than the one that GRAILS_HOME points to, that can sometimes cause peculiar behavior.

I hope that helps.